# What is the best way to collect [0..n], [n+1..l] elements in separate sets using Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, java-stream, hashset

I have a HashSet, I need to collect [0..n] elements in one HashSet and [n+1...l] elements in another HashSet using Java 8 streams. Where `n >=0`  is an arbitrary number, `l >=0` is the length of given HashSet.

```
resultSet1 = set.stream()
.limit(n)
.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The above gives me [0..n] elements.
I could again call `stream()` and then `skip()`, but the thing is HashSet in java is unordered, so there is a probability that the skip method skips the element which was not collected above.

```
resultSet2 = set.stream()
.skip(n)
.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I can use traditional `for`, but a solution using streams will be great.

E.g.
`given set = {1,2,3,4,5}`
`resultSet1 = {1,2}`
`resultSet2 = {3,4,5}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to solve this problem

```
Set firstSet = set.stream()
                  .limit(n)
                  .collect(toSet());

Set secondSet = new HashSet<>(set);
secondSet.removeAll(firstSet);
```

A second way would be

```
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
Set<Integer> set = Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
int n = 2;

Map<Boolean, Set<Integer>> map = 
     set.stream()
        .collect(
             Collectors.partitioningBy(
                 $ -> atomicInteger.addAndGet(1) > n), 
                 Collectors.toSet()
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`partitioningBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.stream.Collector)) with a [`toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet()) downstream collector:

```
int[] i = {0}; // the array is "effectively final"
Map<Boolean, Set<Integer>> map = set.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(x -> i[0]++ < n, toSet()));
```

You can use a `int[]`, which is effectively final, to hold the counter referenced within the lambda, which may mutate its *contents*.